# Rails: ActiveRecord's Base and Relation - why two classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've [read](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface) that "a relation quacks just like a model when it comes to the primary CRUD methods."

Why doesn't Relation do all the work, what's the point of having Base instantiate and then return Relation, which obviously shares its [concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)?

Comment: I agree. Related: [`base`](https://github.com/garybernhardt/base#readme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3, the database behavior was broken out into different mix-ins.  That way, something could do validation without having to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base.  The ActiveRecord::Base class pulls in all the mix-ins needed to do database operations.

Further, relation is not actually a record or record set.  It can remain a germ of a query, so it can be chained until something in the chain returns a record or record set.

So, the where method returns a Relation object.  That object can call where to return another Relation object with another filter in the query.  And so on until the method all, first, count or something is call to make the object returned be the result of the query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't find this comment very useful. I'll take it in parts: not sure how this (1st) answers my question as Relation is not a module, it is a class and instantiated by Base (as I've said). Lazyness, and chainability(2nd and 3d) obviously don't prevent Relation to implement Base functionality, it already does (as i've said). In conclusion, I still don't understand why start off with Base.

Comment: (1) Base brings in other functionality such as validations.  So, the functionality is organized into different parts, (mix-ins or the aggregation pattern as with Relation), and brought together in the user (programmer) API Base class.
(2) The germ nature of relation is complicated, and it's better to isolate all that complication and switch from germ of a query to result set in it's own class and access it through the aggregation pattern from Base.